# Is redirecting a subdomain to point to a folder good practice?

Tags: url, subdomain

I have a blog which can be accessed at

```
http://mysite.com/blog/
```

I would like to access it like this because I think it looks cleaner

```
http://blog.mysite.com
```

I did some reading on domains, subdomains, and redirects and have created a subdomain with the desired URL and re-directed it to the blog path.

Is this a common set up? Is there a better way to accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: Can you please clarify... are you literally _redirecting_ (as in 301 redirect) - which your question suggests - from the subdomain to the folder, so the folder is what appears in the address bar? Or are you using the subdomain as intended - as a subdomain? (The current answers appear to conflict in this respect, one assumes you mean conventional subdomain, the other a redirection.)

Comment: It is a 301 redirect and the folder is what appears in the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that it is a cleaner set-up. However, you cannot redirect the sub-domain to the /blog directory and have it operate as though it is on the sub-domain that I can see. If you are creating a sub-domain not intending for your blog to operate on the sub-domain, then I am not sure why you would do that.

I agree that blogs are cleaner as a sub-domain. If that is what you want to do then I would just redeploy your blog to the sub-domain and create a blanket redirect to the sub-domain from the old blog directory to redirect traffic and search. However, there may be SEO implications to consider before taking on this task. For example, sub-domains are seen as separate sites by search engines and perform on their own. If a blog is integrated into the site for engagement purposes, you may lose that and any search traffic to your blog may not translate to the site and engagement can be lost. It is possible to to have a blog on a sub-domain and still have excellent engagement of course. I am just warning you that there may be more to consider before you jump all in.

Personally, if I were creating a blog, I would put it on a sub-domain because that is just how I like it. I would have to work to stitch the blog to the site and vice-versa.

Now create a good plan and get busy.

Comment: "you cannot redirect the sub-domain to the /blog directory and have it operate as though it is on the sub-domain" not true at all.  See my answer and example below

Comment: @Steve I think there is some confusion/ambiguity with the question. The OP does state "redirect" (although whether they actually mean "redirect" (as in 301 external redirect) and not simply "points to" is questionable; hence my comment above). If you literally _redirect_ the subdomain to the sub-directory then client-side URLs could be incorrect which I think is why closetnoc made that comment. Note that in your answer you have a subdomain which is "not redirected" (as stated in the screenshot). In most hosting control panels there is the additional option of setting up a subdomain _redirect_.

Comment: You may have noticed that I used the phrase *that I can see* making sure that there was room for an answer that I was unaware of. Admittedly, there are newer techniques that do not fit old-school models. Remember that the aged has wisdom and patience and the young must learn these things. Relax grasshopper.

Comment: I didn't consider SEO implications. Most of the traffic to my site goes to the blog at the moment because it is updated more frequently, however I would like it all to contribute to how my site appears to search engines.

Comment: Admittedly, I am old school - that is because I am old and have been at this for a long time. I do not know everything and I know that. There are far more talented young people coming up which pleases me more than you can know. The SEO question is what I thought I could offer. It is possible to have SEO with a sub-domain, but it may be harder to do and may yield less results. Again, I leave it to the young who have newer ideas. I thought I would offer my experience. Good Luck! It was a good question to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a common set up and is perfectly OK.

The internets don't care what directory your site is in, even if the site you are talking about is the root domain e.g. `mysite.com` as long as the document root is set up properly.

For example, in my hosting if people are going to have multiple sites, having the primary domain in public_html and other sites sitting hanging off that directory is pretty untidy.  Instead I make a dummy primary domain e.g. mysites_home.com and then a subdirectory for each domain, then point the document root of the domain to its directory.

This is exactly what you are asking about and, as I said it is common and OK.

Your panel should allow this and it will work transparently and instantly.

In cpanel it looks like this
[image: Cpanel Screen shot]

Comment: However, it seems the OP is doing a 301 redirect from the subdomain to the folder.